# PoCo Logging. Log file name containing timestamp of creation OR New log file every time application starts

Tags: c++, logging, poco-libraries

I need my program to start a new log file in each execution. I want to use PoCo as I am already using this library in the code.

From my point of view, I have two possibilities but I do not know how to configure any of them using a channel in Poco.

- Just starting a new file each time the program starts
- The atual file name (not the rolled but the one that is being writting) containing the timestamp when it was created.

If I am not wrong, using FileChannel is not possible any these possibilities. I guess I could write a new PoCo channel but, obviously, I prefer something already working.

Does anybody have any idea for this. I tried to figure out using two channels but I do not see how.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileChannel has rotateOnOpen property. If you set this to true, it will create new file every time channel is opened. See [FileChannel](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/FileChannel.h#L158). If you do not have this property available, you are using an older version of Poco; in this case, you can simply open File channel with a newly generated name every time your application starts:

```
std::string name = yourCustomNameGenFunc(); 
AutoPtr<FileChannel> pChannel = new FileChannel(name);
```